# Is it permissible to legally change your first name?

Tags: sharia, names, legal

I would like to know whether or not it is permissible in Islam for someone to change their first name (regardless of circumstance)? When I say change, I mean formally as opposed to informally.

I do not have enough knowledge of hadith to ascertain the answer for myself, so your answers will be much appreciated.

I'm primarily after a general 'Sunni' view on the matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I searched and know, it wouldn't be considered as a haram (impermissible) practice from the viewpoint of Sunni (and Shia). Even it could be recommended to change the names which consist of not appropriate meanings.

Answer (score 1):

There is one rule in Islam, that whatever is not forbidden, it is allowed (with come exceptions of-course)

As in Islam, there is no such ruling about if someone can or cannot change name, so this action is mubah (neither recommended nor haram or makrooh) so you can do it without any issues.

(Note: I am not a scholar, so you should better consult a scholar for being 100% sure)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the companions of the Prophet salalahu alayhi wasalam changed there names. It is permissible.